# ember nested model ember-cp-validation

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data

Hello I'm trying to validate a nested model in Ember with ember-cp-validation. It work's fine on the main model but I can't find out a way to link my nested model into the inout helper and so the validations don't work
Model:

```
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
'_id': attr('number'),
'name': attr('string'),
'cookType': attr(),
'pictures': attr(),
'comments': attr(),
'url': attr('string'),
'address': belongsTo('address', {async: false}),
'createdAt': attr('date'),
'updateAt': attr('date'),
'cuisine': Ember.computed(function() {
    return `${this.get('cookType')}`;
})
});
```

My Nested model :

```
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
street:attr('string'),
number:attr('number'),
zip:attr('number'),
town:attr('string'),
country:attr('string')
});
```

My template call :

```
<div class="form-group">
        Rue : {{input type="text" value=(mut (get address street)) class="form-control" name="address.street"}} 
       {{#if (v-get address street 'isValid')}}
            {{fa-icon "check" tagName="span" class="valid-input"}}
        {{/if}}

        <div class="input-error">
            {{#if (v-get address 'street' 'isInvalid')}}
            <div class="error">
                {{v-get address 'street' 'message'}}
            </div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Put a debugger before the line where you are trying to validate the nested model. Step through it and see what you see there.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_debugger